# Versioning CSS and Javascript files automatically in Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, razor, umbraco, versioning, umbraco7

I'm new to both .NET development and Umbraco due to recently starting a new role where I will be working heavily with both. As usual before starting development I am looking for some shortcut or helper functions that will enable me to work more productively. One set of helper functions I have found I have included below:

```
public static string DatedContent(this UrlHelper urlHelper, string contentPath)
{
  var datedPath = new StringBuilder(contentPath);
  datedPath.AppendFormat("{0}m={1}",
      contentPath.IndexOf('?') >= 0 ? '&' : '?',
      getModifiedDate(contentPath));
      return urlHelper.Content(datedPath.ToString());
}

private static string getModifiedDate(string contentPath)
{
    return System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(contentPath)).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
}
```

The functions above are called as follows:

```
<script src="@Url.DatedContent("~/scripts/product.js")"></script>
```

The aim of these functions is to automatically version Javascript and CSS files to ensure that the latest versions of each JavaScript and CSS file are pulled through by appending a modified date query string to the end of the file references.

My issue here is, and I apologise that this is such a newbie question, but where do I put this function in Umbraco 7 or is this functionality already supported?

From what I have learnt so far, content pages all have some base properties that include date created and date modified however CSS and Script files do not have these properties so I cannot simply reference these object properties using inline Razor code and condense them with the ToString method as I am doing the functions above.

My first thought was that these functions could be included at the top of the template where the razor code block is included automatically but as I am new to .Net I don't know if this is a standard convention.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported out of the box.  Except if you use "Client Depencency" framework.  This is a sort of "bundels" framework, similar to the Asp.net framework.

What you do is perfectly possible.  Umbraco is still .Net.

2 ways of getting this code in your site:

- make a new project, build a DLL and drop the DLL in your umbraco website
- put your code in App_code and let IIS build it.

Note: you are checking on EVERY request the modifydate.  If you have a busy website, you will want to optimize this.  E.g. use a partial using @Html.CachedPartial(...) or using a Macro